# Best way to store many to many relationships for fast future querying

Tags: python, pandas, many-to-many

I have a data frame where I am doing multiple regex sub-string searches on one field to determine which "families" this string belongs to. It's a fairly expensive search, so I want to save the results of this in a Pandas column for faster retrieval. Pandas has a nice `isin()` method for determining if a single retrieved item is in a given query set, but I'm not sure how the inverse is meant to be done.

Here's a simple 1-row example:

```
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> example = DataFrame({"text": "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "families": [["famA", "famB", "famE"]]})
>>> example
             families                                         text
0  [famA, famB, famE]  the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

[1 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to be able to query the DataFrame for all rows that contain a certain family relation (e.g. "famA"). What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from the example but would it be possible to store family relations rather than separate columns? For example, you could have columns for each family containing a Boolean. Something like:

```
In [54]: df

Out[54]:
    FamA    FamB    FamC    FamD    FamE    text
0   True    True    False   False   True    the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

It seems like it would be as easy to populate the frame in this way and checking if a particular row is in a particular family would be then trivial. Storing lists in dataframe cells doesn't seem like a good idea here. If you showed an example of how you are generating the lists of families from the strings I might be able to help with populating in this way. Another suggestion which is closer to what you have would be to store the families in a single string rather than a list, something like

```
In [64]:
from pandas import DataFrame
example = DataFrame({"text": "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "families": "famA famB famE"}, index=[0])
example

Out[64]:
    families    text
0   famA famB famE  the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Then you can do

```
In [63]:
example.families.str.contains("famA")

Out[63]:
0    True
Name: families, dtype: bool
```

Comment: For my case there are something like 100+ families and each row has membership to one or few of these; would really prefer tracking membership with a Python object in the dataframe.

Comment: @JoeCondron: Do you need to edit those family memberships after you first assigned them? Or will the performance of editing be (much) less important than querying?

Comment: @jay-tyler Do you know roughly what the maximum number of families per row would be? You could have that many columns containing the families and in cases where a row had fewer you would just have `nan`. e.g. suppose there were no more than 3 families and a particular row was in familiy A and D it would represented by something like  `pd.DataFrame({"text": "the quick br..", "Fam1": "FamA", "Fam2": "FamD", "Fam3": np.nan}, index=[0])` The important thing for performance is that you can check for membership without using your own loops written Python.

Comment: @chris-sc I can't tell as I don't know from the example how they are retrieved/generated in the first place.

Comment: @JoeCondron ups, the question aimed at the jay, sorry. jay-tyler: You will need to make a trade-off here. If retrieving is most important, than the string-storage method JoeCondron proposed will work quite well. What advantages would storing in a list give you? Is it really important?